# Multiple Google Recaptchas in a same page

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have a problem here, I included 2 recaptchas on my page and they are working properly, however at the time of cleaning them (after giving the submit by ajax) I can not reset the recaptcha, if I use the "grecaptcha.reset" it wipes only one recaptcha ..
Thanks!

Comment: why have two in the first place?

Comment: Because I have two forms in the same page: work with us and contact.

Comment: Try adding the captcha IDs to an array, then reset each one in that array?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution, this way u can prepare as many captchas as u need on the same page. Remember to put google api elements: SiteKey and SecretKey!

Back-end:

```
<?php

$siteKey = 'Paste element provided by google api';
$secretKey = 'Paste element provided by google api';

if($_POST['submit']){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey&remoteip=$userIP";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $response = json_decode($response);
    if($response->success){
        echo "Verification is correct. Your name is $username";
    } else {
        echo "Verification failed";
    }
}?>
```

And the front-end:

```
<html>
<meta>
    <title>Google ReCaptcha</title>
</meta>
<body>
    <h3>First form</h3>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Write your name"/>
        <div id="recaptcha1"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"/>
    </form>


    <h3>Second form</h3>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Write your name"/>
        <div id="recaptcha2"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"/>
    </form>


    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit" async defer></script>
    <script>
        var recaptcha1;
        var recaptcha2;
        var myCallBack = function() {

            recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
                'sitekey' : '<?= $siteKey ?>',
                'theme' : 'light'
            });

            recaptcha2 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
                'sitekey' : '<?= $siteKey ?>',
                'theme' : 'dark'
            });
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Cheers!